Is the choice of Measurement-based model specific to the hardware technology?
Most photonic hardware providers seem to prefer Measurement-based quantum computing (MBQC)  over the gate-based model.
Is this due to some limitations of the corresponding hardware technologie?
If yes, for which other hardware technologies, is this model suitable?

In photonic platform, photons do not easily interact with each other, so MBQC is used to apply entangling gates. And also MBQC generally requires large initial resource state(graph state), if using other platforms this is less feasible. But with photons it's easier. But I'm no way an experimentalist, so I'll leave someone else to provide a more comprehensive answer

To add another point: Photons are flying, so you either measure them right now when you have them or let them go somewhere else. You cannot store them without using additional stationary qubits.
